# Record register time and login time on FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

FOSUserbundle

I want to record data  such as createdAt,UpdateAt,loginAt on User table ,when user registers.

What I am thinking is where should I put these cord.

I can find the similar reference

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md

it says overriding /src/Acme/UserBundle/Controller/RegistrationController.php

```
class RegistrationController extends BaseController
{
    public function registerAction()
    {
        $form = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form');
        $formHandler = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form.handler');
        $confirmationEnabled = $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.registration.confirmation.enabled');

        $process = $formHandler->process($confirmationEnabled);
        if ($process) {
            $user = $form->getData();

            /*****************************************************
             * Add new functionality (e.g. log the registration) *
             *****************************************************/
            $this->container->get('logger')->info(
                sprintf('New user registration: %s', $user)
            );

            if ($confirmationEnabled) {
                $this->container->get('session')->set('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email', $user->getEmail());
                $route = 'fos_user_registration_check_email';
            } else {
                $this->authenticateUser($user);
                $route = 'fos_user_registration_confirmed';
            }

            $this->setFlash('fos_user_success', 'registration.flash.user_created');
            $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate($route);

            return new RedirectResponse($url);
        }

        return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('FOSUserBundle:Registration:register.html.'.$this->getEngine(), array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
```

But I dont figure out the way how you can insert data into table with formdata

like

```
$post = $form->getData();
$post->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime()); 
$post->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$em->persist($post);
$em->flush();
```

I am newbie for symfony2.
I think I am still bumping into symfony2's basic logic.
Thank you for your kind reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I have added HasLifecycleCallbacks
and
two functions prePersist,preUpdate

in Acme/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 *
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks 
 *
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{

     /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * 
     */

    public function prePersist()
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime;
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime;
    }

    /**
     * Hook on pre-update operations
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpdate()
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime;
    }
```

THank you for viewing and helping me.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have data peristed in a database, you make your `User` class extend the `FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User` class. After that you will be able to add other entity fields inside.

look at here to know how to extend that class : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

Comment: I have extended FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User and made createdAt,UpdateAt,loginAt columns.

I can insert user row data from form registration,
but I want to insert createdAt automatically when user row is registered.

Answer (score 1):

You can install [**StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle**](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst) and use the **Timestampable** feature.

Then, in your User entity class, you can add:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 */
protected $createdAt;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
 */
protected $updatedAt;
```

Don't forget to add `use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;` at the top for the annotation to work.

This does exactly what you're doing manually with prePersist and preUpdate, but it saves a few lines and keeps the code neater.